# Function to check same values in columns

Tags: c++

Need to make a function which counts the number columns in an array who have unique values

As example:
ARRAY

```
1  2  3  4
2  2  1  4
```

Should count two unique columns which are:

```
1  3
2  1
```

Result should be: 2

This is how far I got, but the code does not work ( gives out wrong column count) and I'm kinda out of ideas.

```
int search_ind(int array[row][col], int r, int c,int column)
{  
    column=0; 
    int i,j,k;

    for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
        for(k=i+1;k<r;k++)              
        {
             if (array[i][j] == array[i+k][j])
                 {                                             
                fail=1;
                break;
             }
             else
                 {
            fail=0;
             }

        }
            if (fail == 1)
            {
               break;
            }
        }
        if (fail == 0)
        {
            column++;
        } 

    }
    printf("With indexes:\nColumn count with unique elements:  %d\n\n",column);        
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is really weird. And you never declared `fail` so this won't even compile; a first hint that this is not _really_ your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: Why do you pass in column as a parameter?

Comment: Not to mention the definitions of `row` and `col` are not provided, and there's no `return` value...

Comment: col, row, fail are defined in main prog

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```
Starting at column 0 loop over all columns
    Save the value of the cell [this column][row: 0] to a variable
    Starting at row 1 of this column loop through all cells of this column
        if this cell is not equal to the variable: break this loop

    We exited above loop without encountering a break. We can increase our matching-columns counter by 1
We looped through all columns. It's time to return the matching-columns counter.
```

By the way: Choose better names for your indices. currentColumn, currentLine etc. instead of i,j,k